# What is the purpose of multiple-level synchronized statement?

Tags: java, multithreading

I really don't understand what purpose of multiple-level synchronized statement? For instance, in the code:

```
static void m() throws Exception {
    synchronized (sync) {
        System.err.println("First level synchronized");
        synchronized (sync) {
            System.err.println("Second level synchronized");
            synchronized (sync) {
                System.err.println("Third level synchronized");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                m();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread th1 = new Thread(r);
    Thread th2 = new Thread(r);
    th1.run();
    th2.run();
}
```

It is impossible to execute the most-enclosing synchronized statement for any thread if some thread has already started to execute one. So, I cannot see any usefulness of such construction. Could you provide an example to understand such using?

An other example of nested synchronized statements can be found in the official JLS specs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19

Comment: I cannot see any usefulness either (unless of course 3 different objects are used as locks instead of a single one). Where have you seen such code?

Comment: Are you sure the blocks where synchronized on the same object?

Comment: I cannot provide such example since this seems really odd.

Comment: @JBNizet It is a bit modification of the code from the JLS, section 14.19.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sure, I'm trying to understand what the section 14.19 means in the example.

Comment: Ah, that example is meant to demonstrate that locks are reentrant - please don't assume that the example in the JLS are _useful_. They are _illustrative_.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Do you mean that multiple monitor lock are unuseful?

Comment: Ah, but the JLS explains what happens when such code is used. It doesn't say it's a good idea to use such code. That said, it's quite frequent to have synchronized methods call other synchronized methods (because the called one could also be called directly). The JLS explains what happens when a single thread synchronizes several times on the same object.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv no, I mean that locking on the same object reference nested several times inside a single method is odd. About multiple monitor, there are circumstances where is valid.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could you provide an example to illustrate multiple monitor using? My question was appeared when I try to invent one.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I cannot think on one example at a time. Anyway, you have the internet to search for it, and probably you won't need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the OP's comments this comes from the [JLS §14.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19)

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        synchronized(t) {
            synchronized(t) {
                System.out.println("made it!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The JLS goes on to say:

> Note that this program would deadlock if a single thread were not permitted to lock a monitor more than once.

This is example is meant to illustrate that `synchronized` blocks are reentrant.

**This JLS is not a document of useful coding practices**.

It is desgined to illustrate how the language is supposed to work. It documents language constructs and defines their behaviour - it is a *specification*.

Answer (score 2):

It's an example of something that is legal, not something that is useful or recommended. It's showing that the lock is recursive ("Note that this program would deadlock if a single thread were not permitted to lock a monitor more than once").